# Disabling Material UI default styles

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using TextField form material-ui. On page it generate `input` element with `Mui-root` styles, like border or border-radius for example.

Is it possible to disable material-ui default styles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own wrapper component that overrides the styles.

For instance, the following would override the root style on the FormControl:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {}
});

export default () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <TextField classes={classes} />
}
```

Note that it overrides classes on `FormControl` because `TextField` passes any unrecognized props to `FormControl`.

You can find all of the classes you can override in the documentation, here: https://material-ui.com/api/form-control/#css

In addition, the TextField is actually made up of multiple components. Have a look at the props here: https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props

So if you wanted to modify the classes on the Input component, you would pass your styles into `InputProps={{ classes: youClasses }}`, for example.

Comment: And is it possible to customize `fieldset`?

Comment: Can you share your code? `<TextField />` doesn't contain a fieldset, so something you're passing must be creating it.

Comment: Check here: https://codesandbox.io/s/r1o7l3lyxp I'm using v4 of material-ui, as the classes have changed. Noticable is the addition of the notchedOutline class on `Input`, which was absent in 3.9.3. 

Docs for 4.0: https://next.material-ui.com/api/text-field/

Comment: @Cereal - thanks, you have pushed me in the right direction

Comment: what about our class? how do we add it?

Comment: @ichimaru use the className prop